# php matching 2 arrays : key value store against array values

Tags: php, arrays

```
$a = array('x' => 1, 'y' => 2, 'z' => 3, 'a' => 4, 'b' => 4);
$b = array('x', 'z', 'a');
```

I am looking for a NATIVE PHP function that will take the 2 above arrays and return

```
array('x' => 1, 'z' => 3, 'a' => 4);
```

I do not want to use a loop.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_intersect_key($a, array_fill_keys($b, 1));
```

There is native function **array_intersect_key** which computes the intersection of several arrays using their keys as base. But your second array is a list of values which we need to be keys. So we can use function **array_fill_keys** which take first argument as list of keys and create an array filled with value, specified by second parameter ( we will take integer 1, for instance ):

```
$b = array('x', 'z', 'a');
$bValsToKeys = array_fill_keys($b, 1);
```

$bValsToKeys will be

```
Array ( [x] => 1 [z] => 1 [a] => 1 )
```

And then we can intersect it with $a:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($a, $bValsToKeys);
print_r($result);
```

Out:

```
Array ( [x] => 1 [z] => 3 [a] => 4 )
```

Comment: Please, explain a little bit what you are doing. Otherwise, this answer is not useful at all

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved using `array_intersect_key` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and `array_flip` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php);

```
array_intersect_key($a, array_flip($b));
```

See this example; https://eval.in/158360